# pyomo model constraint programming for "SEND+MORE=MONEY" task

Tags: optimization, constraints, solver, pyomo

Trying to build a pyomo model to solve "SEND+MORE=MONEY" task.

```
C4 C3 C2 C1
    S  E  N  D
+   M  O  R  E
______________
 M  O  N  E  Y
```

Model building:

```
from pyomo.environ import *    
m = ConcreteModel()

m.letters = Set(initialize = ['S', 'E', 'N', 'D', 'M', 'O', 'R', 'Y'])
m.tens = Set(initialize = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'])

m.let_val = Var(m.letters, bounds=(0,9), initialize=9, within=Integers)
m.ten_val = Var(m.tens, within=Binary)

m.C1 = Constraint(expr =  m.ten_val['C3'] + m.let_val['S'] + m.let_val['M'] == m.let_val['O'] + m.ten_val['C4']*10)
m.C2 = Constraint(expr =  m.ten_val['C2'] + m.let_val['E'] + m.let_val['O'] == m.let_val['N'] + m.ten_val['C3']*10)
m.C3 = Constraint(expr =  m.ten_val['C1'] + m.let_val['N'] + m.let_val['R'] == m.let_val['E'] + m.ten_val['C2']*10)
m.C4 = Constraint(expr =  m.let_val['D'] + m.let_val['E'] == m.let_val['Y'] + m.ten_val['C1']*10)
m.C5 = Constraint(expr =  m.let_val['M'] == m.ten_val['C4'])
m.C6 = Constraint(expr =  m.let_val['M'] == 1)

m.f1 = Objective(expr = m.let_val['S']*1000 + m.let_val['E']*100 + m.let_val['N']*10 + m.let_val['D'] + 
                 m.let_val['M']*1000 + m.let_val['O']*100 + m.let_val['R']*10 + m.let_val['E'], sense=minimize)

solver = SolverFactory('glpk')
results = solver.solve(m)

print('  ', int((value(m.let_val['S'])*1000 + value(m.let_val['E'])*100 + value(m.let_val['N'])*10 + value(m.let_val['D']))))
print('+ ', int((value(m.let_val['M'])*1000 + value(m.let_val['O'])*100 + value(m.let_val['R'])*10 + value(m.let_val['E']))))
print('=', int((value(m.let_val['M'])*10000 + value(m.let_val['O'])*1000 + value(m.let_val['N'])*100 + value(m.let_val['E'])*10 + value(m.let_val['Y']))))
```

'glpk' solution:

```
   9000
+  1000
= 10000
```

'ipopt' solution:

```
   8942
+  1057
= 10000
```

Ipopt is closer but not good enough. I had to help solver and add to constraints (C5 and C6). Without it the answer is 0.

I couldn't find any information about how to declare instructions that all letter values should be different from each other.
How it can be done?

How to solve such a task with pyomo correctly?

Comment: For MIP formulations of the all-different constraint see: Williams, H. Paul and Yan, Hong (2001), Representations of the 'all_different' predicate of constraint satisfaction in integer programming, Informs Journal on Computing, 13 (2). 96-103.

Comment: @Erwin Kalvelagen. Thank you for the article reference. It is quite funny that in this article the same task is reviewed. I also read your other posts of 2016 and 2017 about this problem. It is quite clear in theory but I don't have enough skill and experience to realize it in code. So in practice it is totally unclear.
I wonder why there is no code examples for this problem. Couldn't find anything in pyomo docs. Find nothing on experience exchange forums. The practical application in optimization area for beginners is too hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

m = ConcreteModel()

m.letters = Set(initialize = ['S', 'E', 'N', 'D', 'M', 'O', 'R', 'Y'])
m.vals = RangeSet(0, 9)
m.tens = Set(initialize = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'])

m.ten_val = Var(m.tens, within=Binary, initialize=0)
m.x = Var(m.letters, m.vals, within=Binary, initialize=1)

def c_rule(m, i):
    return sum(m.x[i, j] for j in m.vals) <= 1 
m.col = Constraint(m.letters, rule=c_rule) # not more than one value for the letter

def r_rule(m, j):
    return sum(m.x[i, j] for i in m.letters) <= 1
m.row = Constraint(m.vals, rule=r_rule) # not more than one value for the digit

m.C1 = Constraint(expr = m.ten_val['C4'] == m.x['M', 1])
m.C2 = Constraint(expr = m.x['M', 1] == 1)
m.C3 = Constraint(expr =  m.ten_val['C3'] + sum(m.x['S', j]*j for j in m.vals) + m.x['M', 1] == sum(m.x['O', j]*j for j in m.vals) + m.ten_val['C4']*10)
m.C4 = Constraint(expr =  m.ten_val['C2'] + sum(m.x['E', j]*j for j in m.vals) + sum(m.x['O', j]*j for j in m.vals) == sum(m.x['N', j]*j for j in m.vals) + m.ten_val['C3']*10)             
m.C5 = Constraint(expr =  m.ten_val['C1'] + sum(m.x['N', j]*j for j in m.vals) + sum(m.x['R', j]*j for j in m.vals) == sum(m.x['E', j]*j for j in m.vals) + m.ten_val['C2']*10)
m.C6 = Constraint(expr =  sum(m.x['D', j]*j for j in m.vals) + sum(m.x['E', j]*j for j in m.vals) == sum(m.x['Y', j]*j for j in m.vals) + m.ten_val['C1']*10)

m.f1 = Objective(expr =  sum(m.x['S', j]*j for j in m.vals), sense=minimize) # we are searching for working solution, no matter what to minimize

solver = SolverFactory('glpk')
results = solver.solve(m);
```

```
x_leters = [i for i, v in m.x.get_values().items() if v == 1]
digits = {}

for i in m.letters:
    val = 0
    for j in x_leters:
        if i in j:
            val = j[1]
    digits[i] = val

print(' ',digits['S'],digits['E'],digits['N'],digits['D'])
print('+',digits['M'],digits['O'],digits['R'],digits['E'])
print(digits['M'],digits['O'],digits['N'],digits['E'],digits['Y'])
```

```
  9 5 6 7
+ 1 0 8 5
1 0 6 5 2
```

Great job!